# How to use alias in webpack to override a dependency already existing in node_modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, node-modules

In Webpack 4,

I want to place my `rsg-components` instead of the one in `node_modules`.

So `react-styleguidist` will import my version instead.

Apparently `resolve.alias` doesn't take precedence over `node_modules`, is there a way to do so without forking `react-stylguidist` ?

Comment: How did you conclude that `resolve.alias` doesn't take precedence over `node_modules`? According to docs, it **looks like** it does https://take.ms/RSJFg https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [resolve-modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules).
Just add the directory where your module is before `node_modules`.

From the documentation:

> If you want to add a directory to search in that takes precedence over node_modules/:

```
modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"]
```